# Map Info to WKT format

Tags: mapinfo, well-known-text

I have files in Map Info format(TAB,DATA,etc) and I want to convert them to WKT(well-known text) format, so that I can store in a DB. do any of you know how to convert Map Info to WKT?

Comment: Do you have access to MapInfo? If yes, then it is easier for you to use EasyLoader to upload data into a database. If the answer is no, then you should write more information about which database is in question so we could help you.

Comment: I have files in MapInfo format and i want the output data in WKT format files.

Comment: Some time ago I wrote a converter in C#, see [MIF/MID -> WKT](https://pastebin.com/K535BHDr) to get an impression. However, it converts from MIF/MID files not MapInfo native TAB files. It is also limited to `Region`, Point, Line, Text and MultiPoint are not supported because these are not required for my application. I think objects like "Rounded Rectangles" or "Ellipses" you cannot express in WKT (see [Well-known text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)), so there you would face a problem anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick help, you could use

https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/mapinfo-to-wkt

Upload all MapInfo files (TAB, DAT, ID, MAP) and do a conversion.
The result will be CSV file with attributes and added column for WKT definition for all objects in it.

Comment: yes, i tried that. but looks like they have limitations on the number of files and size of files.